# How to remove Buttons, Pagination in VF Page when enhancedlist tag is used?

Tags: visualforce, list-view, page-override

I have to Overide Lead Tab view to show Multiple List views Data has blocks in Same Page

So I've created a VF page Like this

```
<apex:page >
<Apex:pageBlock title="t1">
   <apex:pageBlockSection columns="3" showHeader="false">
     <apex:enhancedList rowsPerPage="10" listId="00B90000008hlhA" height="300" customizable="true"/>
    <apex:enhancedList rowsPerPage="10" listId="00B90000008OBmE" height="300"/>
       <apex:enhancedList rowsPerPage="10" listId="00B90000009Dw7C" height="250"/>
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
   </Apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

and Result is this
[image]

Is there any way to remove the Buttons(New Lead , Change Owner), Pagination, Alphabets, Create New View LINK..etc. in vf Page

OR Should I write Custom List view Controller to show only Data

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS visibility property to hide the buttons.

```
.yourbuttonClass { visibility: hidden }
```

To get the class of a button go to developer console of your browser.

Comment: In case it is helpful for future readers, for me the equivalent of `.yourbuttonClass` was `input.btn`, final code `<style type="text/css"> input.btn {visibility : hidden } </style>`